# Determining if an integer is a square in a finite field

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Looking at the elliptic curve C: $Y^{2} = X^{3} + X + 2$ in the finite field $\mathbb{F_{13}}$.

I first looked at the line $X = 2$, which yields $Y^{2}= 12$, and was "lucky" and saw that $12+13 = 25 = 5^{2}$, so that the intersections between the line and the curve are $(2,-5),(2,5)$

When I then looked at $X = 3$, I got $Y^{2} = 32 = 6\mod13$ and I am stuck.

Surely there is a better way of deciding whether an integer is a square in a group than trying the approach of

$6 + 13i = x^2?$ until it works. And when would you even know to stop?

Comment: Trial and error in a set with $13$ elements is very straight forward.  But the [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) is a good way to tell if a natural number is a square $\pmod p$ for prime $p$.

Comment: @lulu i will look into legendre, thanks

Comment: In addition to Legendre symbol you can use the result (due to Euler IIRC) that an integer $a$ coprime to $p$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$ if and only if $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv1\pmod p$. This may look like a useless thing, but because we have [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) this is actually quite fast on a computer. Much faster than factoring, which is what using the Legendre symbol may entail. You don't want to use it in paper and pencil work, so it depends... :-)

Comment: A few other caveats apply. For example, do you just want to know whether the number is a square, or do you actually want to also find the modular square root? If $p\equiv-1\pmod 4$, then Euler kicks in. If $a$ is a quadratic residue, then $a^{(p-1)/2}\equiv1$. So $a^{(p+1)/2}\equiv a$, and therefore $a^{(p+1)/4}$ can serve as a square root of $a$. Alas, I'm not aware of a similar trick for the case $p\equiv1\pmod4$, but I'm fairly sure that methods much more efficient than systematic search exist.

Answer (score 1):

For small $p$ such as $p=13$ it only takes a few seconds to compute $k^2\pmod{p}$ for $0\leq k\leq\frac{p-1}{2}$, yielding all squares mod $p$.

For large $p$ the [law of quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol#Legendre_symbol_and_quadratic_reciprocity) gives a fast way to determine whether a number is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: yes, but then p = 23714713 arrives

Comment: That is not a prime.